# Possible to get the size of an Elasticsearch index through Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have been trying to get the size of my Elasticsearch index through the Java API, and I have not been able to find the right call to accomplish this.  I found some suggestions like this one (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/jNCjCqAS1us), but it is from 2012 and seems to no longer be relevant.

I have been able to get an `IndicesStatsResponse` the following way:

```
IndicesStatsResponse response = client.admin().indices()
        .prepareStats(makeIndexName(tenant.getId()))
        .clear()
        .setStore(true)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

but from this point I cannot find the information that I need.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index stats can be accessed using the [Stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/indices-stats.html).

- Using cURL: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/index_name/_stats?pretty=true` where under `store` you have `size_in_bytes`
- Using the `Java API`: `IndexStatsResponse` is a response that has to be converted to a JSON if you want to read it. You can use `gson` to parse te Json.

  ```
      IndicesStatsResponse indicesStatsResponse = StartTCPService.getClient()
              .admin()
              .indices()
              .prepareStats(index_name)
              .all()
              .execute().actionGet();

      XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
      builder.startObject();
      indicesStatsResponse.toXContent(builder, ToXContent.EMPTY_PARAMS);
      builder.endObject();
      String jsonResponse = builder.prettyPrint().string();

      JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser(); // from import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
      Long sizeOfIndex = jsonParser.parse(jsonResponse)
              .getAsJsonObject().get("_all")
              .getAsJsonObject().get("primaries")
              .getAsJsonObject().get("store")
              .getAsJsonObject().get("size_in_bytes").getAsLong();

      System.out.println(sizeOfIndex); // this is in Bytes
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

With `RestHighLevelClient`, tested with es `7.1.0`:

```
RestHighLevelClient client = ...;

var resp = client.getLowLevelClient().performRequest(new Request("GET", "INDEX_NAME/_stats"));
var body =  new ObjectMapper().readTree(resp.getEntity().getContent());
var size = body.get("indices").get("INDEX_NAME").get("primaries").get("store").get("size_in_bytes");
```

I use `Jackson` to parse json.

Comment: This is perfect.
Once I have resp.getEntity().getContent(), I have all the information I need

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
IndicesStatsResponse response =client.admin().indices().prepareStats(indexName).clear().setStore(true).execute().actionGet();
ByteSizeValue bsv = response.getIndex(indexName).getTotal().getStore().getSize();
```

Comment: indexName is name of your index

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.